# Glassfish certificate and Grizzly PortUnification exception

Tags: glassfish, grizzly

Trying to import a certificate in pfx format into my Glassfish domain's keystore. It appears to work successfully, but the domain refuses to start up with the error "GRIZZLY0059: PortUnification exception."

I'm using Glassfish 3.1, with Grizzly 1.9.31-1. A few others have had this error, and one suggestion was to upgrade Grizzly (claiming this was a known bug, fixed in 1.9.43). pkg doesn't let me update Grizzly though ("No updates necessary for this image"). Is there a way to force it to upgrade to a more recent version?

This may not even be the issue anyway, but I can't figure out what else it could be

Comment: Please try Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've upgraded to 3.1.2.2 (Grizzly 1.9.50-1 now), but the problem is still there

Comment: can you pls. file an issue @ https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY and provide more details w.r.t. domain.xml configuration. thx!